# Preamble generation of narrowband signals

Tags: lte, preamble

I have to generate a complex sine wave with a sampling frequency of 1.92MHz and subcarrier spacing of 3.75kHz. The number of FFT points is 512. The narrowband frequency is 180kHz.

I also have to generate a preamble. The preamble looks like this:

```
pattern = (1:48); % In this way you have all the 48 sub-carriers;
q = diag(pattern); 
n= repmat(0:L-1, 48,1);
X_ref = exp(1i * 2 * pi * q * n/ L); % symbol
ofdm_ref = [X_ref(:,L-N_CP + 1: L) repmat(X_ref,1,5)]; %SG
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You laid out your problem, do you have a more specific question?